# Importing Clip with Alpha Transparency into Resolve

Tags: davinci-resolve, alpha

Working on a video for a client with a third party animation company.

I need to figure out a file format they can export video with alpha transparency, that Resolve will import correctly.

Ordinarily I use the following settings to export video (say from After Effects) with alphas that Resolve can understand...

Quicktime, RGB + Alpha, Straight (Unmatted), Apple Prores 4444

But this company use Windows machines, and cannot export ProRes. They've tried sending me PNG encoded MOV files but Resolve can't even open them.

Does anyone know what file formats - that can be easily rendered to from say Cinema 4D or After Effects - that Resolve will be able to ingest properly preserving alpha transparency?

Comment: After Effects is totally able to export Prores 4444 on Windows. I do it every day. But for heaven's sake, use image sequences like a professional, Quicktime is for amateurs.

Comment: Just to clarify - the version of AE that the third party company I'm working with uses is outdated and cannot export prores on windows. Can you be specific about the image sequence settings you'd use. As a 'professional' editor and shooter, I do not usually work with transparency in this way.

Comment: Tiffs are quickest, support alpha and are lossless. I used to use pngs, which are smaller, until someone wised me up on how slow they are to read and write. Just render as an image sequence (there are pre-made image sequence output modules, I'm pretty sure one is tiff sequence) and Resolve will be able to open it as if it was a movie file.

Comment: Thanks, thats very helpful.